# Online doctor consultation?

Tags: blood-tests

I'm interested in paying a doctor to chat with me online to help explain my blood test results. Does such a thing exist? And do you know of any affordable good options?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/jobs so maybe post a job offering there?

Comment: Charging a fee for medical advice is practicing medicine, and medial licenses aren't usually valid across international and even state/province borders. So such a service would have to be very limited geographically, or illegal in most places.

Answer (score 2):

[Teladoc](https://www.teladoc.com/) is one that is offered as a benefit from the company that I work for, when enrolling in their health insurance. I don't know what the price would be if you're not on a health insurance plan that covers them, but I can tell you that, for me, the copay for Teladoc is about 1/4 the copay of seeing a doctor in person, for the particular health insurance plan that I'm currently enrolled in.

I have no affiliation with the company, other than that they're offered as a benefit from the company I work for. I don't know if they offer service without a membership or not.

I've found there are other similar services, such as

https://www.doctorondemand.com/

or

https://www.mdlive.com/

The pharmacy Walgreens also lists the service, but they seem to use one of the previously mentioned services (MDLive):
https://www.walgreens.com/topic/pharmacy/virtualdoctor.jsp

Hope that helps.

Comment: It doesn't appear that the first two companies accept individuals, and if Walgreen's offering is available to individuals, it's limited to a handful of US states.